# Why is this message spamming my server log?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, server-administration

Lately, I've started seeing this a lot in my Minecraft server log:

```
Attempted to place a tile entity where there was no entity tile!
```

Sometimes I see it a lot, sometimes not at all.

What does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Internally, the game refers to blocks as "tiles" and non-blocks (mobs, dropped items, minecarts, etc.) as "entities".  Some blocks need extra information associated with them (chests have inventories, furnaces have cook times, …) which are stored as *invisible* entities called "tile entities".  The blocks which have entities associated with them are then "entity tiles".  (These are all debug terms; the average player shouldn't ever have to worry about them.)

An error message occurs when, during a chunk load, a tile entity is found, but it's matching entity file isn't.  In this case, the entity was one which can contain items (such as a chest, furnace, or dispenser).  This can happen because:

- the chunk's data was corrupted
- an installed mod was incorrectly written or has been uninstalled
- good old game bugs (go beta!)

The game is good about recovering from such things — the orphaned tile entity is simply discarded and the chunk continues loading — but it does mean *something* has gone wrong.

Comment: Wow. I really *was* way off!

Comment: Could it have anything to do with the minecart that I have infinitely looping over a piece of rail?

Comment: @John — Don't feel too bad about being off — the words we as players use aren't the same as the ones Notch uses in his code (hence `BlockContainer` instead of, say, `TileWithInventory` or some such).

Comment: @John — It shouldn't be a proper entity (like a minecart) that causes it, but a complex block/tile like a furnace, dispenser, etc.  If you're modding or have modded in the past, that would be my first guess (I've caused this error for myself in the past while modding).  If you're running a prerelease, those are especially buggy.  Other than that?  No real way to make a good guess; the error doesn't even tell you *where* in the world the problem occurred.  :-/

Comment: Hmm, well I guess I won't worry about it seeing as it's a 100% vanilla 1.8.1 (no prereleases) server.  Do pistons have tile entities? My minecart repeatedly opens and closes a piston.  Could something like this happen if the minecart changes the state of the piston before the piston loads?

Comment: @John — I haven't looked at piston operation in great detail, but I believe they do create tile entities while in motion (but not at rest, even while extended).